# first letter not in span

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to change the first letter of an h2 tag thats NOT in a span in the following chunk of code

```
<h2>
    <span class="subtleHeader">Saskatoon, Regina and Edmonton's</span><br>
    WEB DESIGN EXPERTS
</h2>
```

So in this example I want to change the W. yes I can change the dom, but I'm very very lazy and have this DOM structure in many places and was wondering if there was a css way to do it.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not with CSS alone. `:first-letter` will only pick up the very first letter (and any punctuation marks), and you can't select or apply pseudo-elements to DOM text nodes with CSS.

You'll have to wrap that title in its own span, then select the `:first-letter` of that second span.

Comment: @thirtydot: Actually, I just woke up.

Comment: @BoltClock Never knew that selector existed! +1

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS applies to **elements**, not to **text**. If you still wish to edit text only, you'll need a language that is able to work with strings, such as Javascript or PHP.

Or use the selector @BoltClock suggested.

I'd do that.